# Decltype of optional member

Tags: c++, option-type, decltype

I'm trying to get the type from struct member that is in a std::optional<> that is the return type of a member function.

This is a simplified example:

```
struct Result
{
    int tag;
    int pos;
};

class Dict
{
public:
    std::optional<Result> search(const char *word)
    {
        return Result{ 1,2 };
    }
};
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    Dict abc;
    decltype(abc.search(const char*)->pos) position;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Making function public and fixing syntax `decltype(abc.search("")->pos) position;` should work fine. It is not clear what are you trying to ask here.

Comment: Sorry it was meant to be public.  No way to do it with parameter types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pass an actual parameter to `search`, it will work (along with making `search` public):

https://wandbox.org/permlink/0Q3mLW7SmQW4QshE

```
#include <optional>

struct Result
{
    int tag;
    int pos;
};

class Dict
{
public:
    std::optional<Result> search(const char *word)
    {
        return Result{ 1,2 };
    }
};

int main()
{
    Dict abc;
    decltype(abc.search("")->pos) position;

    return 0;
}
```

The parameter to `search` doesn't have to be valid (in terms of what your function expects - because it won't actually call it), it just has to be the correct type.

If you want to deal directly with types, and not instances, as your comment suggests, then @Jarod42 points out you can use the following line for your variable declaration:

`decltype(std::declval<Dict>().search(std::declval<const char*>())->pos) position;`

https://wandbox.org/permlink/kZlqKUFoIWv1m3M3

Though I probably don't need to point out how unreadable a ~70 character variable type is. I think if it were me I would either just use an `int`, or I would create a type alias for `pos`, e.g. `using ResultPositionType = int;` then use that within your `Result` struct, and again in `main`.

Comment: I'd prefer if I could use a parameter type, the real code is more complicated and the parameter is a vector<pair<string,int>>.

Comment: @Rlyeh use `{}` if it's unambiguous. But why you can't just use `Result().pos`?

Comment: `std::declval` might help in general case, when we don't have object directly: `decltype(std::declval<Dict>().search(std::declval<const char*>())->pos)`

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42, hadn't thought of that, this is perhaps closer to what OP wanted. I'll add that into the answer.

Comment: Yes, type aliases are the solution. I'd probably make it so that `Dict::ResultType::PosType` existed. (Heh, just noticed the username again)

Comment: @Jarod42 `decltype(abc.search(std::declval<const char*>())->pos)` was something like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Mark showed the direct answer to your question.

However, I propose an easier-to-read solution that borrows the standard library's heavy reliance on type aliases. They're basically free, if a little noisy in class definitions:

```
#include <optional>

struct Result
{
    using TagType = int;
    using PosType = int;

    TagType tag;
    PosType pos;
};

class Dict
{
public:
    using ResultType = Result;

    std::optional<ResultType> search(const char* word)
    {
        return ResultType{ 1, 2 };
    }
};

int main()
{
    Dict abc;
    Dict::ResultType::PosType position;
}
```

This has the benefit of being self-documenting, and not requiring a 70-character statement that only C++ Standardese native speakers can understand. :)

It also has value inside the class definitions themselves, because now you have one place to set these types and, semantics allowing, can alter them more easily than in the past (when you'd have had to modify every single member function, every single data member…).

One downside is that the int-ness of the two `Result` members is not quite as obvious. Whether that is a problem depends on your real code, in particular the actual size of `Result` and how it's often used. As a compromise, you might consider dropping the type aliases at that level, keeping only `Dict::ResultType` then digging into it with `decltype(declval<Dict::ResultType>().pos)`. Only you can decide how far to go with this approach.